# rdrobust package with covariates returns too many coefficients

Tags: r, package

I am running rdrobust function from rdrobust package with covariates option. I am using the guide by the authors ("A practical Introduction to regression discontinuity design" 2019 Cattaneo, Idboro, Titiunik). At R snippet 26 the code is like that:

```
# R Snippet 26
# Using rdrobust with covariates
Z = cbind(data$vshr_islam1994, data$partycount, data$lpop1994,data$merkezi, data$merkezp, data$subbuyuk, data$buyuk)
colnames(Z) = c("vshr_islam1994", "partycount", "lpop1994","merkezi", "merkezp", "subbuyuk", "buyuk")

out = rdrobust(Y, X, covs = Z, kernel = 'triangular', scaleregul = 1, p = 1, bwselect = 'mserd')
```

According to the authors there should be one set of coefficients gamma on Z (equation 4.3 in the guide on p.79) However in the output return there are two per variable (so they are order of p+1) and they are also not symmetric on left and right side as they should be:

```
> out$beta_p_r
                      buyuk     merkezi      merkezp     lpop1994    subbuyuk partycount vshr_islam1994
[1,] 15.7202048  0.02413397  0.42115723  0.066234600  8.285038847 0.054458918 5.80939355     33.6301014
[2,] -0.1623748 -0.00151349 -0.00525247 -0.001610547 -0.005106353 0.003832462 0.01467446      0.7929476

> out$beta_p_l
                      buyuk     merkezi      merkezp   lpop1994    subbuyuk  partycount vshr_islam1994
[1,] 12.8148371 0.017154325 0.478279531 0.0300389537 8.24125708 0.049303686 5.854047932     33.1039297
[2,] -0.2058053 0.001048017 0.009266473 0.0006171706 0.02126247 0.001227102 0.003424324      0.7899774
```

What are these coefficients? I only know the first unnamed vector corresponds to local linear function (example has p=1) for regression discontinuity. But the rest is a mystery and they do not match the above guide. I am concerned that estimation with covariates is not how it is described and would like to know what is the estimated equation if it is different from that described in the guide.

Answer (score 1):

This is now fixed in the latest version of the package. Those coefficients did not have any useful meaning, as they are used in preliminary steps.